# Params.Size not correctly set

Tags: delphi, informix, delphi-xe7, firedac

Situation is as follows:
With upgrading from XE3 (anyDAC) to XE7 (Firedac), we suddenly are getting issues on updating a charachter field > 255 characters on Informix.

We now get the error :

> '[FireDAC][Phys][ODBC]-345. Data too large for variable [#1]. Max len
>   = [256], actual len = [1000] Hint: set the TFDParam.Size to a greater value'

Problem is we are using cached update mode in combination with use of 'applyupdates', so we don't have any parameters to set (except for the PK)...

FYI: the table definition where we want to update a record:

```
CREATE TABLE com_monster_im ( 
monim_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
com_monster CHAR(1000),
PRIMARY KEY(monim_id));
```

The FDQuery components consists of following query:

```
SELECT monim_id, com_monster
FROM com_monster_im
WHERE monim_id = :paramMonimId
```

We don't use persistent fields or whatsoever.

Comment: Curious.  It looks like you may be hitting a bug in a 'FireDAC' ODBC driver, or you need to configure your ODBC driver as it says.  Error -345 might be from Informix, but the lengths would not normally be part of an Informix message, so FireDAC is doing some interpreting.  Using CHAR(1000) is expensive; you should review using LVARCHAR(1000) instead unless your data will normally be almost all of 1000 bytes long.  Informix itself (e.g. via Informix ESQL/C) will be OK with being passed a CHAR(1000) value -- heck, it'll take CHAR(32000) without problem.  So I think the trouble is in the driver.

Comment: Jonathan, I know the dimension of a char(1000) is not ideal, but this table is a legacy table... Changing the data type to lvarchar can't be done for the moment...  But it's my opinion too I hit some bug in the firedac driver.

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping rule like this:

[image: Data mapping rule to add]

And the error will disappear